# JFrame not being made at right dimensions

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This code, when run, will make a window but not at the specified dimensions. What is wrong with it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Windowing {
    void JFrame(){
        JFrame frames = new JFrame("Total recall");
        frames.setSize(1000,8000);
        frames.setVisible(true);
        frames.pack();
        //Buttons push = new Buttons();
        //((Buttons) push).buttons();
        JTextField wager = new JTextField(1);
        wager.setSize(100,200);
        wager.setVisible(true);
        wager.setLocation(100, 200);
        frames.add(wager);
        //frames.add(push);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a number of "opportunity areas" here.

- To start, it seems like you set frame size to 1000x8000 because you didn't see any change  right?
- Secondly you call `setVisible` on the textField because you didn't see that either.
- And finally you're setting the size of the textfield ( I guess because you're seeing it take the whole frame )

The problem here is that you have to invoke `pack` and `setVisible` at the end of the construction. Also, you have to learn how to use layout managers and frames.

Swing, is very powerful, but it is a bit hard to grasp at the beginning.

These two links will be helpful:

- [How to make frames](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)
- [Using Layout Managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

I've changed your code and the result looks like this:

[image]

Here's the modified source code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Windowing {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        Windowing windowing = new Windowing();
        windowing.showFrame();
    }
    void showFrame(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Total recall");
        JButton push = new JButton("Push");
        JTextField wager = new JTextField(15);

        // Panels do have "FlowLayout"
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(wager);
        panel.add(push);

        frame.add( panel );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could remove the call to `frames.pack()`; it overrides the previously set frame size.

However, what you *really* want to do is remove the `frames.setSize(1000,8000)` and move `frames.pack()` down to the bottom of the method; that will ensure that the frame is big enough to display its contents but not too big to fit on the screen.

If you call `pack` before adding anything to the frame (like you are doing now), it will make the window extremely small; it's probably appearing near the upper left of your screen, but you won't notice it unless you know where to look.

Comment: Could he move the `setSize()` call to after the `pack()` call?

Comment: Sure, but that would make the frame too big to fit on the screen. And it's pointless to use *both* methods of setting the frame's size.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `setPreferredSize(Dimension)` instead.